# $|e^a-e^b| \leq |a-b|$ for complex numbers with non-positive real parts

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

Came across this problem on an old qualifying exam: Let $a$ and $b$ be complex numbers whose real parts are negative or 0. Prove the inequality $|e^a-e^b| \leq |a-b|$.

If $f(z)=e^z$ and $z=x+iy$, then $|f'(z)|=e^x\leq 1$ given that $x \leq 0$. I played around with the limit definition of the derivative, but wasn't able to get anywhere. Not sure what else to try; a hint would be very helpful!

Comment: can you please mention in which Qualifying exam it has appeared,would be helpful for practice @dls

Comment: @BAYMAX Idk if it's still useful to you, but it came in the TIFR PhD entrance test in 2017.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Consider integrating $f'(z) dz$ along the line segment from $a$ to $b$

Comment: Neat. But could anyone explain this idea further?

Comment: This takes another approach to the mean-value theorem -- the integral approach. It works neatly with holomorphic functions (and the MV theorem itself isn't very elegant), but I still would've liked to see the connection drawn.

Answer (score 3):

Prove and then use the following fact:

Let $D \subseteq \mathbb C$ be a convex region and let $f: D \to \mathbb C$ be holomorphic with $|f'|\le 1$ on $D$. Then for $a,b\in D$ we have

$$ |f(b) - f(a)| \le |b-a|$$

Comment: What I'd also like to see here is a reference to the mean value theorem, and why although it fails in general with complex functions the norm can still be bounded (similarly as with vector-valued real functions).

Answer (score 2):

An interesting related article A norm inequality for Hermitian operators by
Ritsuo Nakamoto

The American Mathematical Monthly; Mar 2003; 110, 3;

Answer (score 0):

If you put $\exp(z)$ in [here](http://davidbau.com/conformal/#%28exp%28z%29%29) and turn what you see about how two complex numbers $z$, $w$ in the left half plane $\Re(z)\le 0$ suffer under the map $\exp$ into a statement, that statement would be exactly the wanted inequality.

Answer (score 0):

A brute force approach, avoiding complex analysis, just to prove it can be done.

Let $a=a_1+a_2i, b=b_1+b_2i.$

Then $$\begin{align}\left|e^a-e^b\right|^2&=e^{2a_1}+e^{2b_1}-2\operatorname {Re} e^{a+\overline b}\\&=e^{2a_1}+e^{2b_1}-2e^{a_1+b_1}\cos(a_2-b_2)\\&=(e^{a_1}-e^{b_1})^2+2e^{a_1+b_1}(1-\cos(a_2-b_2)).\tag1\end{align}$$

And we need to show $(1)$ is $< (a_1-b_1)^2+(a_2-b_2)^2$ when $a_1,b_1<0.$ It turns out, we can show this term by term.

We get the real inequality $$\left|e^{a_1}-e^{b_1}\right|\leq |a_1-b_1|$$ for $a_1,b_1<0,$ from the mean value theorem.

So we finally need, since $0<e^{a_1+b_1}<1,$

$$2(1-\cos \theta)\leq \theta^2.$$

But $$\frac{1-\cos\theta}2=\sin^{2}\frac{\theta}2\leq \frac{\theta^2}{4}$$ so $2(1-\cos\theta)\leq \theta^2.$

We get strict inequality in the first terms when $a_1\neq b_1.$ And if $a_1=b_1,$ we get strict inequality when $1-\cos(a_2-b_2)\neq 0,$ since, when non-zero, the term $e^{a_1+b_1}$ makes it strictly smaller.

But for strict equality with the left side zero, $(a_2-b_2)^2=0.$

So we get the strict inequality when $a\neq b.$