# Prove that $|e^{a}-e^{b}|<|a-b|$

Tags: complex-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$|e^a-e^b| \leq |a-b|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54507/ea-eb-leq-a-b)

Could someone help me through this problem? 
Let a, b be two complex numbers in the left half-plane. Prove that $|e^{a}-e^{b}|<|a-b|$

Comment: By no mean this is true...

Comment: I think that being in the complex plane if this inequality can be fulfilled

Comment: Oh... Sorry I read a little bit too fast, there is a condition with the half-plane. But that's funny, nobody seems to see it, two wrong answers already ;)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54507/ea-eb-leq-a-b

Comment: The old question only asks for a non-strict inequality, but a minimally careful bound on the integral suggested by GEdrgar there will show the stricy inequality as asked here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By mean value theorem,
$$ |e^a - e^b| \leqslant |a-b|\max_{x\in [a,b]} e^x $$
But $a$ and $b$ have a negative real part, and then all $x$ in $[a,b]$ also have a negative real part. Hence the $\max$ is less than one. And thus
$$ |e^a - e^b| <|a-b|. $$

Comment: Mean value theorem does not hold for complex-valued functions.

Comment: @dls — I think I gave a wrong name, what is the english name for the theorem I used ?

Comment: the mean value theorem holds for complex functions

Comment: The mean value theorem for derivatives does not hold for complex-valued functions. The standard example is $f(x)=e^{ix}$ on the interval $[0,2\pi]$. Then $f(2\pi)-f(0)=0$ but $2\pi|f'(x)|=2\pi$ for every $x$.

Comment: @dls — But still, the $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq \max_{z\in[x,y]} |\nabla f(z)|$, by integrating. What is the name of this inequality ?

Comment: @Lierre I'm not aware of a name. In the one-variable real case, I just know it as a property of the integral.