# Proof: complex exponential inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, exponential-function

Let $z_1,z_2$ be two complex numbers with $\operatorname{Re}(z_1)\leq0$ and $\operatorname{Re}(z_2)\leq0$. I want to prove: $$\big|e^{z_2}-e^{z_1}\big|\leq\big|z_2-z_1\big|$$

I began by using the reverse triangle inequality: $\big|e^{z_2}-e^{z_1}\big|\geq\bigg|\big|e^{z_2}\big|-\big|e^{z_1}\big|\bigg|$

So, it must be shown that: $$\frac{\bigg|\big|e^{z_2}\big|-\big|e^{z_1}\big|\bigg|}{\big|z_2-z_1\big|}=\bigg|\frac{e^{\operatorname{Re}(z_2)}-e^{\operatorname{Re}(z_1)}}{z_2-z_1}\bigg|\leq1$$

Why is this true?

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/136075/42969.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, by the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_for_vector-valued_functions), there is some $z$ in the line segment joining $z_1$ to $z_2$ such that$$\left|\frac{e^{z_2}-e^{z_1}}{z_2-z_1}\right|\leqslant\left|e^z\right|.$$But $\operatorname{Re}(z_1),\operatorname{Re}(z_2)\leqslant0\implies\operatorname{Re}(z)\leqslant0$ and therefore $\left|e^z\right|=e^{\operatorname{Re}(z)}\leqslant1$.

Comment: Regarding the last inequality, I would better say $\vert e^z \vert = e^{{Re}(z)} \le 1$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to consider a segment connecting $z_1$ and $z_2$ that has $Re(z) \leq 0$.  Then
$|e^{z_2} - e^{z_1}| = |\int_{z_1}^{z_2} e^z dz| \leq \int_{z_1}^{z_2} |e^z| dz \leq \int_{z_1}^{z_2} 1 dz = |z_2 - z_1|$.