# $|\mathrm{e}^{z}- \mathrm{e}^{w}| \leq |z-w|$ for $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : \mathrm{Re}z \leq 0 \}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm looking at this pretty easy problem, but I need the final argument for the mean-value property that I'm looking for. The problem goes like this.

> Prove that if $V = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : \mathrm{Re} z \leq 0 \}$, then
>   $$|\mathrm{e}^{z}- \mathrm{e}^{w}| \leq |z-w|$$ for $z,w \in V$.

So my idea is obviously to apply the mean-value theorem for $f(z) = \mathrm{e}^z$ and bound it by $$\left| \frac{f(z) - f(w)}{z-w}\right|\leq 1.$$ But how do I argue that $$\frac{f(z) - f(w)}{z-w} \leq f'(0)?$$ This would finish the problem immediately.

Comment: You can integrate the derivative over the segment, $e^z - e^w = \int_w^z e^\zeta\,d\zeta$, which with the standard estimate yields $\lvert e^z-e^w\rvert \leqslant \lvert z-w\rvert \cdot \max \lvert e^\zeta\rvert$, which is $\leqslant \lvert z-w\rvert$ for $z,w$ in the lower half plane.

Comment: That's even better. You're my savior today Daniel, haha. I might post some more questions soon on complex variables problems I've been pondering about for a while. Kind of in a complex analysis frenzy.

Comment: This is the same question as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54507/ea-eb-leq-a-b , but I'm not going to vote to close or flag as a duplicate because of the possibility that there is an alternate solution, perhaps not requiring complex contour integration, merely complex arithmetic.  If any more experienced users think this is a bad reason not to vote to close or flag a question as a duplicate, please tell me.

Comment: @BoSchmidt :there is kind of a weak generalization of the Mean Value Theorem to functions of a complex variable, which is what you're trying to use here, but I don't think it gives you what you need.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Generalization_in_complex_analysis, scroll down to "Generalization in Complex Analysis"