# Exponentials inequality: $|e^x + e^y| \leq |x - y|$ for $x,y<0$.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, inequality, lipschitz-functions

I am trying to prove $|e^z - e^\omega| \leq |z - \omega|$ for $z,\omega\in\{z\in\mathbb{C}\;:\;\Re(z)<0\}$ and I get stuck in an inequality of the stated in the title : $|e^x + e^y| \leq |x - y|$ for $x,y<0$.

This is what I have tried:
\begin{equation}\left|e^z - e^\omega\right| = \left|e^{i\Im(z)}\right|\left|e^{\Re(z)} - e^{\Re(\omega)}e^{i(\Im(\omega) - \Im(z))}\right| \leq \left|e^{\Re(z)} + e^{\Re(\omega)}\right|
\end{equation}

Is it true that $|e^x + e^y| \leq |x - y|$ for $x,y<0$? If yes, any help will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: That's not true...

Comment: Quickly drawing the graph, it seems like it's only true for some combinations of $x$ and $y$. For example, $x=y=-1\Rightarrow$ not true

Comment: Okay thanks! Any suggestion to prove the main result $|e^z - e^\omega| \leq |z - \omega|$ for $z,\omega\in\{z\in\mathbb{C}\;:\;\Re(z)<0\}$?

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/48rjtvpres

Comment: A really useful graph! Thank you Matti P.

Comment: dudas, please check your claim! Others can't judge the answers otherwise. Do you want a bound for $|e^z-e^w|$ or $e^x+e^y$? Hint: one of them is trivially wrong, and you seem to have accepted an answer arguing for the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove $|e^z-e^w|\le|z-w|$ for $z$ and $w$ of negative real part, consider
$$|e^z-e^w|=\left|\int_w^z e^u\,du\right|.$$
Here the integral is over a straight line segment, of length $|w-z|$
from $w$ to $z$, and $|e^u|<1$ on it. Therefore $|e^z-e^w|\le|z-w|$.

Comment: You write $|e^z-e^w|$ though while the question says $|e^z+e^w|$

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thank you!!

Comment: @vrugtehagel Indeed, but we now know this was a typo.

Comment: I very much doubt that as he's written that three times. Sure it may not be the cause of his question, but it still is his question.

Comment: @vrugtehagel The question **never** says $|e^z+e^w|$.

Comment: If $|e^z-e^w|\le|z-w|$ is the actual question then it can be closed as a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/54507.

Answer (score 2):

Um, take $x=y=-1$;

$$|e^{-1}+e^{-1}|>|x-y|=0$$

seems like your theorem isn't true.

Comment: Okay thanks! Any suggestion to prove the main result $|e^z - e^\omega| \leq |z - \omega|$ for $z,\omega\in\{z\in\mathbb{C}\;:\;\Re(z)<0\}$?

Comment: $-1$ is still in $\mathbb{C}$ with $\Re(-1)<0$, so even then it's not true.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality $|e^x + e^y| \leq |x - y|$ is not true for all $x,y <0$.

Suppose that we have  $|e^x + e^y| \leq |x - y|$  for all $x,y <0$.

With $x \to 0$ and $y \to 0$ we would get $2 \le0$. !

Comment: Okay thanks! Any suggestion to prove the main result $|e^z - e^\omega| \leq |z - \omega|$ for $z,\omega\in\{z\in\mathbb{C}\;:\;\Re(z)<0\}$?